# Checking support for _Generic() selection in C

Tags: c, generics, gcc, clang, c11

I use macro generic selection to "overload" some functions in my custom library and i want to make it as portable as possible, so i'm trying to check whether generic selection support is present by doing

```
#if ((__STDC_VERSION__>=201112L) || ((__GNUC__*10000+__GNUC_MINOR__*100+__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)>=40600) || ((__clang_major__*10000+__clang_minor__*100+__clang_patchlevel__)>=30100) || (__xlC__>=0x1201))
```

(CHECK THE EDIT NOTE ON THE BOTTOM TO SEE ACCURATE COMPILER VERSIONS)

As these compiler versions should support SOME c11 features, but i'm not actually sure whether generic selection is actually supported on these versions;
could anyone confirm? alternatively is there another way?

.

.

EDIT:
compiler version that support _Generic keyword are actually:

```
((__GNUC__*10000+__GNUC_MINOR__*100+__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)>=40900) || ((__clang_major__*10000+__clang_minor__*100+__clang_patchlevel__)>=30000) || (__xlC__>=0x1201)
```

Comment: Since `_Generic` is mandatory for C11 compilers, the STDC_VERSION check alone should suffice.

Comment: @Lundin, The problem is that C11 support isn't atomic. Do you update `__STDC_VERSION__` after finishing C11 support? Then there's a chance `_Generic` is supported, but other things aren't yet and the version macro isn't updated. Do you update it partway through support? Then there's a chance it's updated without `_Generic` being supported.

Comment: @Lundin __STDC_VERSION__ alone would not suffice as some C compiler versions support some C11 features even without using actual C11 (which is also my case (GNU compiler))

Comment: FWIW, this kind of problem is why C++ has started to introduce [feature test macros](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations) with a more `#if __c_generic` solution instead of needing to check the entire language and/or compiler version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strict way to check this is

```
#if __STDC__==1 && __STDC_VERSION >= 201112L
```

A compiler may only define `__STDC__` to the value 1 if it is a conforming implementation (reference: C11 6.10.8.1). Any conforming implementation with `__STDC_VERSION >= 201112L` must implement `_Generic`.

There may however be compiler versions that supported `_Generic` before they had full C11 support - those you have to find in some compiler-specific way.

Comment: I agree that this is the best answer available.  I observe, however, that the standard only binds *conforming* implementations, which makes the `__STDC__` macro a bit paradoxical, and which therefore, in principle, makes solutions based on it less than wholly reliable.

Comment: You can't stop a non-conforming compiler from claiming conformance.  But it comes down to QoI — quality of implementation.  If the compiler makes misleading claims, it probably won't get used.

Comment: While I aggree with the spirit of your answer, this does not really help. I know of at least one major vendor implementation that sets `__STDC__` to that value and has a buggy implementation of `_Generic`.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not obvious if you actually have an `#else` part, that is an alternative strategy if there is no `_Generic`. If you don't have that, the whole "testing" is a bit pointless. A well defined *use* of `_Generic` towards the start of the file would help to have the compilation fail with an error message:

```
_Static_assert(_Generic(0, default: 1), "we need _Generic");
```

Comment: my code is a little bit big, anyway it would work both with and without overloading, but overloading makes functions simpler and allows the user to use both foo(String *a, char *b) and foo(String *a, String *b). I have to macro that are use to check whether overloading is present: _STRINGLIB_OVERLOADING_ and _STRINGLIB_NO_OVERLOADING_ ; the latter can also be defined by the user before including the library to manjually disable function overloading

Comment: How about `_Static_assert(_Generic(0, default: __STDC__), "we need _Generic");`

Comment: @Lundin that would only compile if _Generic() keyword is present, it would otherwise intepret it as non static; that said _Static_assert is C11 only if i remember correctly, and my library is supposed to work with all standards (that's why i'm checking for keyword support on the first place)